# Rails 3 - Rescuing a Mysql2::Error: Table doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception

I have an iteration in which I am calling `set_table_name` for some model. The idea is that in each iteration, the model changes its table. Sometimes, the table won't exist, in that case, an error of this kind will happen:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'db_name.table_name_xyz' doesn't exist
```

I want the iteration to keep running and not abort because of the error. I've wrapped the `set_table_name` line of code with a `begin` and `rescue`, but no exception seems to be raised as the script instantly aborts on error (it doesn't execute the `rescue` code). Here's the code:

```
((start_year)..(start_actual_year)).each do |year|
      begin
        Data.set_table_name("Secciones#{year}#{year + 1}")
      rescue Exception => e
        next
      end
end
```

Can I rescue this kind of error? What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are catching the exception correctly? Here's [more info](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html) if needed.

```
begin
  # Your code here.
rescue Exception => e
  # Output the exception that it is catching.
  puts e.message
ensure
  # The ensure block is used to close a db connection if needed.
end
```

Comment: Hi. I've edited my original post to include the exception handling code. It's similar to the example you've put